# Moving deleted rows from one table to another table (has the triggers as well) using ms sql

Tags: java, sql-server

I have two tables called `Active_QC1(id, req_name, req_type)` and `Deleted_QC1(id, req_name, req_type)`. In case I delete data from the `Active_QC1` table, that data should move to the `Deleted_QC1` table. Both tables can have triggers.

Can anyone guide me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OUTPUT clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) (microsoft.com) in a DELETE statement. The basic outline for a simple delete statement would be something as follows:

```sql
DELETE FROM Active_QC1 
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO Deleted_QC1
WHERE id=5;
```

What it does is delete all rows in `Active_QC1` with `id=5`, then inserts those rows into `Deleted_QC1`.

An example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Active_QC1(id INT, req_name VARCHAR(128), req_type INT);
CREATE TABLE #Deleted_QC1(id INT, req_name VARCHAR(128), req_type INT);

INSERT INTO #Active_QC1(id,req_name,req_type)
VALUES
    (1,'engage',3),
    (2,'forward',5),
    (3,'obliterate',3),
    (4,'reply',5),
    (5,'delete',5);

DELETE FROM 
    #Active_QC1
OUTPUT 
    DELETED.id,
    DELETED.req_name,
    DELETED.req_type 
INTO 
    #Deleted_QC1(id,req_name,req_type)
WHERE 
    req_type=5;

SELECT*FROM #Deleted_QC1;

DROP TABLE #Deleted_QC1;
DROP TABLE #Active_QC1;
```

This script makes two temporary tables `#Active_QC1` and `#Deleted_QC1` with identical table definitions. Some rows are added to `#Active_QC1`. The `DELETE` statement deletes all rows in `#Active_QC1` with `req_type=5`, and inserts them into `#Deleted_QC1`. The script finally selects all rows in `#Deleted_QC1`. The result is the following:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║     id ║ req_name ║ req_type ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║      2 ║ forward  ║        5 ║
║      4 ║ reply    ║        5 ║
║      5 ║ delete   ║        5 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to add one column to Active_QC1 table that names `Status_Flag` its `varchar` type and set status flag 'Y' or 'N' as corresponding to deleted or not. then you can try following queries

Query #1:

```
ALTER TABLE Active_QC1
ADD Status_Flag VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)
```

Query #2:

```
UPDATE Active_QC1
SET Status_Flag = 'Y' 
WHERE id = <deleted records id>
```

Query #3:

```
INSERT INTO Deleted_QC1 (id, req_name, req_type)
    SELECT id, req_name, req_type
    FROM Active_QC1
    WHERE Status_Flag = 'Y';
```

Query #4.

```
DELETE FROM Active_QC1
WHERE Status_Flag = 'N';
```

Comment: I think this solution is ultimately slower (if you grow your database a lot, then you get a lot of deleted entries which in many cases will slow down searches in the main table).